# Python/Selenium text in td without span text

Tags: python, html, selenium, html-table

The html code is

```html
<td>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-down arrow-green"></i>
    <span class="fs_buy">Strong Buy</span> 
    1.11
</td>
```

if I use this code

```py
cccss ='//*[@id="fs_title_values"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]'
about = driver.find_element_by_xpath(cccss)
RatingCurrentValue=about.text
print ('RatingCurrentValue', RatingCurrentValue)
```

I will get all text: RatingCurrentValue Strong Buy 1.11

My goal is to get only the 1.11 without the text in the span tag.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value `1.11` Use `javascripts executor` and get **lastChild** of the `td` element.

Induce `WebDriverWait()` and `visibility_of_element_located()`

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="fs_title_values"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]')))
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', element))
```

You need to add following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

---

**UPDATE**:

```
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fs_title_values"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]')))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. But add 3 libraries for this simple task is very heavy. Is there a simplier method.

Comment: @EduardBauer : This is the best practice to include wait to avoid any page sync problem in selenium.If you don't want use this just try updated one.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the child node text from the full text to get parent node text.

```
cccss ='//*[@id="fs_title_values"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]'


full_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(cccss).text

child_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(cccss + “//span”).text

parent_text = full_text.replace(child_text, '')
print(parent_text)
```

Comment: Thank you. That's it. But it must be called parent_text = full_text.replace(child_text, '')

Comment: @EduardBauer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The extract the text **1.11** from the element you can use the following  [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based solution:

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[//span[@class='fs_buy' and text()='Strong Buy']]").get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[2])
```

---

Ideally, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following *XPATH* based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[//span[@class='fs_buy' and text()='Strong Buy']]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[2])
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```